# Button gets css properties on pc but not on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have input type="submit" with css properties (as height, width, ...) and on PC Safari browser it works, but on iPhone Safari browser submit button doesn't have right properties.

```
HTML 
<input type="submit" class="send" name="send" value="Send">

CSS
.send, .send:link, .send:visited{
display: inline-block;
padding: 12px 52px;
background-color: #033E8C;
border: 4px solid #033E8C;
border-radius: 0px 32px;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.7s, -webkit-box-shadow 0.7s;
transition: background-color 0.7s, -webkit-box-shadow 0.7s;
transition: background-color 0.7s, box-shadow 0.7s;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 16px #033E8C;
box-shadow: 0 0px 16px #033E8C;
}
.send:hover, .send:active {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #033E8C;
box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #033E8C;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

On iPhone submit button looks like default sending button without properties. Only border works, padding and other doesn't work.

Comment: You'll likely need to add `-webkit-appearance: none` as well. Also, those pseduoclasses (`:link`, `:visited`) are used on hyperlinks, not `form` elements.

Comment: You thought this?
.send{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 52px;
    background-color: #033E8C;
    border: 4px solid #033E8C;
    transition: background-color 0.7s, -webkit-box-shadow 0.7s;
    transition: background-color 0.7s, box-shadow 0.7s, -webkit-box-shadow 0.7s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 16px #033E8C;
            box-shadow: 0 0px 16px #033E8C;
            -webkit-appearance: none;}
.send:hover, 
.send:active {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #033E8C;
            box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #033E8C;}